# How to change source video based Query String in JS

Tags: javascript

first im sorry if my english bad.

How To change **CHANGE_THIS** besed from ID query in video source by JS.

example : if i access "localhost/index.html?id=video" source will change from "/files/**CHANGE_THIS**/1080p" to "/files/**video**/1080p"

```
<head>
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.3.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="poster.jpg" data-setup='{"fluid": true}'>
<source src="/files/CHANGE_THIS/1080p" type='video/mp4'>
</video>

<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.3.0/video.js"></script>

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give the source id :

```
   <source id="source" src="/files/CHANGE_THIS/1080p" type='video/mp4'>
```

then in javascript :

```
   var url_string = window.location.href;
   var url = new URL(url_string);
   var c = url.searchParams.get("c");
   document.getElementById("source").src="/files/"+c+"/1080p" //your source
```

Answer (score 0):

First you want to grab the video element, which can be done with [`document.getElementById('my-video')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). Then you want to grab the `<source>` element, which can be done with [`document.getElementsByTagName('source')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName). Note that this return a `NodeList` collection of all elements, even though there's only one in your example. As such, you'll need the first index, as `document.getElementsByTagName('source')[0]`. Finally, you simply want to set the `.src` of the source to be the `.id` of the video, plus what it was before.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
const video = document.getElementById('my-video');
const source = document.getElementsByTagName('source')[0];
source.src = video.id + source.src;

console.log(source.src);
```

```html
<video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="poster.jpg" data-setup='{"fluid": true}'>
<source src="/files/CHANGE_THIS_BY_QUERY/1080p" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

Note that you'll likely want to remove the first `/`, as that denotes the root of the website. Depending on your folder layout, you'll probably want to add this slash in manually, by removing it from the original source and making use of `source.src = video.id + / + source.src`.